# Учебные материалы по алгоритмам

Tags: алгоритм, книги

Добрый вечер. Очень интересны различные алгоритмы, наподобие (нахождения кратчайшего пути (программно)) и тому подобное. 
Для меня коды алгоритмов очень не читабельны и мозг их категорично не воспринимает.Возможно,вы,знаете подробные материалы или видео-материалы, буду очень благодарен. Заранее спасибо.

P.s про кратчайший путь знаю, что лучше по алгоритму дейкстры искать, на листке посчитаю граф, а программно - уже нет(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Классический учебник по алгоритмам: [Introduction to Algorithms, Thomas H. Cormen, Charles E. Leiserson, Ronald L. Rivest, Clifford Stein](http://en.tjcities.com/wp-content/uploads/Books/Algorithms_3rd.pdf), но он с псевдокодом. Если вас интересуют менее традиционные методы, то, к примеру для сортировок, есть [алго-ритмичесткие танцы](http://www.youtube.com/user/AlgoRythmics?feature=watch).

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужна книга "[Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2429691/)" (Томас Х. Кормен, Чарльз И. Лейзерсон), в ней алгоритмы представлены с теоретической точки зрения и в виде псевдокода, довольно внятного для восприятия.

Comment: Хорошо, что Кормен переведён.

Comment: Оу, 2 почти одинаковых ответа и почти одновременно =) Программисты думают одинаково =)

Comment: Мы все вышли из Корменовой шинели ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Посоветую такой ресурс: http://e-maxx.ru/algo/. Алгоритмы разбиты по категориям (Графы, Структуры данных, Алгебра и т.д.). Помимо реализации на C++ у каждого алгоритма есть описание, сферы применения, а иногда даже доказательство корректности.

Как альтернативу учебникам можно предложить online-курсы от Р. Седжвика: части [I](https://www.coursera.org/course/algs4partI) и [II](https://www.coursera.org/course/algs4partII). Темы объясняются предельно ясно и подробно. В качестве языка для реализации используется Java. А заодно и в английском поупражняетесь.